# How to correctly split unbalanced dataset incorporating train test and cross validation set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, cross-validation

[image: This is the portion of text I'm trying to replicate in terms of sampling.]
The picture above is what I'm trying to replicate. I just don't know if I'm going about it the right way.
I'm working with the FakeNewsChallenge dataset and its extremely unbalanced, and I'm trying to replicate and improve on a method used in a paper.

---

Agree - 7.36%

Disagree - 1.68%

Discuss - 17.82%

Unrelated - 73.13%

I'm splitting the data in this way:

(split dataset into 67/33 split)

- train 67%, test 33%

(split training further 80/20 for validation)

- training 80%, validation 20%

(Then split training and validation using 3 fold cross validation set)

As an aside, getting that 1.68% of disagree and agree has been extremely difficult.

---

This is where I'm having an issue as it's not making total sense to me. Is the validation set created in the 80/20 split being stratified as well in the 5fold?

Here is where I am at currently:

---

Split data into 67% Training Set and 33% Test Set

```
x_train1, x_test, y_train1, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)

x_train2, x_val, y_train2, y_val = train_test_split(x_train1, y_train1, test_size=0.20)

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle = True)
skf.getn_splits(x_train2, y_train2)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(x_train2, y_train2):
  x_train_cros, x_test_cros = x_train2[train_index], x_train2[test_index]
  y_train_cros, y_test_cros = y_train2[train_index], y_train[test_index]
```

Would I run skf again for the validation set as well? Where are the test test sets from skf created being used in sequential model?

---

Citation for the method I'm using:

Thota, Aswini; Tilak, Priyanka; Ahluwalia, Simrat; and Lohia, Nibrat (2018) "Fake News Detection: A Deep Learning Approach," SMU Data Science Review: Vol. 1 : No. 3 , Article 10.
Available at: https://scholar.smu.edu/datasciencereview/vol1/iss3/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add one more parameter in the function 'train_test_split()':

```
x_train1, x_test, y_train1, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, stratify = y)
```

This will give you equal distribution of all target categories.

Comment: Would this apply to both `train_test_split()`?

Comment: Yes apply both the 'train_test_split()' function....

Comment: this would only split the data in train and text sets. How to validate the model on test data?

Comment: Suppose you have 100 target values out of which 40:'YES' and 60: 'NO' categories and you want to split 80/20 proportion in train/test data. Now by appling 'stratify' your data will get splited as : train('YES')=40*0.80 = 32, train('NO') = 60*0.80 = 48, test('YES') =40*0.20 = 8, test('NO') = 60*0.20 =  12

Comment: @SuryaLohia. Would I need to the StratifiedKFold(), or could I use the StratifiedKFold to just split my dataset into folds without creating test sets? I don't exactly know exactly where I would use those test sets generated by stratifiedKFold with Keras.

Comment: @StackPancakes As you have already used stratify on train_test_split() ,So you don't have to use StratifyKFlod(), rather use KFold(). Moreover can you please tell me what exactly you want to do? Are you a beginner to Machine Learning and trying to build some models to predict traget variable? Please provide me futher details.

Comment: It will be great favour if you vote my answer if it helps you. Thank you

Comment: @SuryaLohia. No, I wouldn't say I'm a beginner at ML. It's probably combination of working too long and this darn dataset is what's messing with me. The fakeNewsChallenge is a multi-label classification problem to classify article - headline pairs using stance detection (e.g. does the headline agree, disagree, discuss, unrelated with the article body). A method I'm using is to get the TF-IDF headline and article as well as cosine similarity and concatenating them together. Then it's fed into a fully connected NN with a drop layer between the two layers.

Comment: @StackPancakes Ok than you need not have to use cross validation here as your dataset is uniform now, build the model by using this data and tune parameters. Thank you

Comment: Just want to update you. I just went back on created the training and test set twice. I just use stratified train and test set once 67/33 split, and used validation 0.1 in keras model. Really nice results.

Comment: Great. Happy coding